# Can a bounce rate drop from 50% to 10% after event tracking is added in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, responsive-webdesign, bounce-rate, event-tracking

I launched a total redesign of a site one week ago to add responsive design, good interlinking, related content recommendations and such. After that the bounce rate dropped just a little from 50% to 48-49% and stayed like this for 5 days.

5 days passed and I implemented event tracking on links, buttons, menus, form submissions, video plays and such.

I don't know if it was the reason or not, but the last 2 days bounce rate dropped to 10%+ yesterday and to 9%+ today.

Is this possible? 10% sounds too good to be true.

Comment: You are not alone,  see also: [Why might Google Analytics report a sudden, but persistent, drop in bounce rate (70% to 12%)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/121360/why-might-google-analytics-report-a-sudden-but-persistent-drop-in-bounce-rate)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google [says](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide):

> By default, the event hit sent by *_trackEvent()* is considered an 
>   *interaction* hit, which means that it is included in bounce rate 
>   calculations.

So if someone triggers one of your events, it is then not considered a bounce.  You can get around this by adding an `opt_noninteraction` parameter to your `_trackEvent()`

Comment: One might however argue that a visitor with events should not count as a bounce at least as long as events are triggered by user actions (after all the user has interacted with the site). Depending on the scenario the lower bounce rate might be more accurate.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I would like to discuss this question about adjusting bounce rate by noninteraction or not, but on there such questions are often suspended because of speculations.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of that approach as well, but if the interaction matches one of your websites KPIs (e.g. a download if your purpose is to disseminate information) then it's no longer a matter of speculation; analytics is supposed to track KPIs. What I think is utterly wrong is to send events not caused by interactions just to lower the bounce rate.