# High GA Bounce Rate Issue

Tags: google-analytics, bounce-rate

[image]
Enormously high bounce rate on our blog & individual blog posts as well.  We use Yoast SEO premium plugin on our blog. Some changes went live on the website on 1st May and we are not able to figure out what could be the reason for this sudden jump of 60% in the bounce rate.

This graph is comparing Organic Traffic Bounce Rate vs the Average.

[image]
In the second image, we have compared our metrics with the benchmarks shared inside GA app. According to this table, everything looks okay. However, this table doesn't allow you to slice & dice by landing pages and allowing only to compare blog pages.

Can someone help to debug as to what could be the reason for this high bounce rate? Share any advice on what should be checked.

Comment: See also that somebody had the opposite problem: bounce rate improved drastically an they wanted to know what could have cause it:  [Why might Google Analytics report a sudden, but persistent, drop in bounce rate (70% to 12%)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/121360/why-might-google-analytics-report-a-sudden-but-persistent-drop-in-bounce-rate)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your worst performing traffic, bounce wise, is referral and it began May 2nd. I would recommend opening the analytics for your Acquisition > All Traffic > Referrals and take a look at what site specifically started sending you more visitors that seem to be low quality, or seeking information your site is not providing. If there is an irrelevant backlink on a referrers site maybe you can ask them the remove it.